# Update select dropdown list on filtering js-grid data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsgrid

I want to update the select box list on filtering event of jsgrid.
I read the documentation but there is no such feature for JsGrid.In the fiddle there is a country dropdown which has different countries.
When i give input in Age as `29` it return `2` rows with country as `China & Russia`.
So on this filtering i want to update the select box list with only `China & Russia` and on giving blank input or removing all the filter items it should update the dropdown with original countries list.
I had searched a lot ,i didn't find any solution.
Fiddle link -
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9sxcsurk/2/)

Comment: Did you try to change `items` property of the select field with `$("#grid").jsGrid("fieldOption", "yourSelectFieldName", "items", newItemsSet)`?